# No HDMI output (neither sound nor video) after upgrading to 20.04

Tags: graphics, hdmi, 20.04

After Upgrading from 19.10 to 20.04 the HDMI output is no longer working. It doesn't appear on the display settings at all.

```
lspci | grep 'VGA'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake)
```

What can I do to get this thing working?

I am working on a Tuxedo Infinitybook Pro 14 v3.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it has something to do with the Kernel Version.
The above desribed problem was with Kernel 5.4
After rebooting with Kernel 5.3 the HDMI output worked perfectly fine.
Maybe I have to wait for a fix in 5.4...

Comment: how did you install a lower kernel version? I hqve no second monitor in 5.4 but its nothing exotic, Intel drivers, 60hz 1920x1080

Comment: I booted into the old available kernel via grub. But apparantly the old kernel was purged and is not longer available.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with 5.4 kernel & Intel i7 8550U processor with UHD 620 graphics. The report seems to allude to my monitor, Vizio 43" 4K,  resolution of 3840x2160 in the DMESG log... Since my monitor refresh is capped at 30Hz vise 60Hz I see no video. I do see the proper hdmi monitor settings in DMESG for all settings however the output fails... all previous version of Ubuntu have allowed hdmi 2160 res at 30Hz refresh successfully from initial offering provided I loaded the Intel driver previously. Now Intel graphics are supposed to be baked into the kernel modules. Module i915 is loaded in the kernel as well. 
I also note the failures of the hdmi sound from DMESG outputs. Seems this processors modules are not well vetted for this version?

If I change monitors to anything else I get perfect video...

EDIT

I ended up enabling ssh and found setting the display down to 1920x1080 60 Hz using xrandr remotely and this allowed my 4K hdmi port to come up on the Vizio Monitor..

ssh sesssion $  DISPLAY=:0 xrandr --size 1920x1080 -r 60  << works on kernel 5.4

I am using a port on the Monitor labeled for 4K @30Hz however it only works at 1080P 60Hz.. on this new kernel

I do have 2 other PCs that are Intel i7 CPU one Win10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS that can do 4K @ 30Hz on other hdmi ports successfully, I tried all of them with the 20.04 PC and only the lower resolution is working now.

Hopefully this 4K bug is worked out soon on the 5.4 kernel ...  I am on 5.4.0-29-generic

This fix must be done every time I want to see the display on my 4K monitor for now...